# Blazor shown wrong HTML character codes

Tags: html, blazor

I am using a complex object whose values are represented with **Blazor**. Among others there is a list of strings. Some **strings contain a bullet**, but these are **represented as rectangles**.

**How can I manipulate the display so that the bullets are displayed?**

My string:

[image]

razor file:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < @item.Highlight.Count() && i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="searchHighlight">@((MarkupString)@item.Highlight[i])</div>
    }
```

The bulled at the html page:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code where you're outputting the string data?

Comment: @Waragi I add the code to the initial article.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace • with the HTML equivalent `&#x2022;`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @item.Highlight.Count() && i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="searchHighlight">@((MarkupString)@item.Highlight[i].Replace("•", "&#x2022;"))</div>
    }
```

Then casting it as **MarkupString** should render it properly.

Comment: It's not working. I also tried it already (in the cs file).

Comment: If you just try to render &#x2022; on the razor component does it display properly? If not, it's an issue with CSS probably.

Comment: To proof I set: <div class="searchHighlight">&#x2022; @((MarkupString)@item.Highlight[i].Replace("•", "&#x2022;"))</div> OR <div class="searchHighlight">@((MarkupString) "&#x2022;")</div>. The test pullet is shown fine.

Comment: From the break point, see if you can copy that exact character. Maybe you're replacing the wrong one?

Comment: Yes, I can copy the character, but I did not find a generator where I could insert the character and get the html code for it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Worth a shot: https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder

Comment: That is interesting. When I mark the bullet, copy it and paste it into the web2generator or somewhere else, it appears as rectangle just like at the Blazor page. I got no glue how this can be.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to imitate the same string data as you have, and, unfortunately, I could not reproduce this issue. It is pretty hard to tell where is the problem: CSS, fonts, metatags, string itself or something else. Anyways, according to the positive reaction to Waragi's suggestion, you could try some of these options:

Try to put bullet point HTML Unicode outside of your razor parentheses, like this:

```
<div class="searchHighlight">&#x2022;@((MarkupString)item?.Highlight.Replace("•", ""))</div>
```

Also, you can avoid adding a bullet point HTML Unicode above by adding some styles to `searchHighlight`:

```
<div class="searchHighlight">@item?.Highlight.Replace("•", "")</div>

<style>
    .searchHighlight::before {
        content: "\2022";
    }
</style>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It is not that I want bullets before every item?.Highlight, but following your idea I can hide the rectangle. It's better to hide the symbol than to show the wrong symbol. So for now my solution is: 

<div class="searchHighlight">@((MarkupString)@item.Highlight[i].Replace("", ""))</div>

Comment: So probably the CSS solution will suit best for you (in case you need some unicode symbols anyway), until you find a real cause of this issue. Good luck!

Comment: Btw, have you tried testing the output in the browser with the default font (if you use a different one)?